# How to install tablefunc in postgres on Mac OS X?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I used StackBuilder to install Postgres 9.2 on my Mac OS X machine.

Now I need to use tablefunc and it seems that the function is not available.

How do I install the contrib package on the Mac?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html

Comment: Thanks - In fact it was enough to execute CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

I tought I need to install some module...

Answer (score 25):

As suggested by a_horse_with_no_name the solution was simple.

I just had to execute:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Comment: using this, I ran into the next issue `ERROR:  materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context`