# syntax error at or near "START" in Postgres despite the fact that EXTENSION tablefunc is created

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query, connect-by

I have a query like this(which works in Oracle properly):

```
...
            LEFT JOIN myTable ON ....
            START WITH orgNodeId IN (
                SELECT someColumn FROM anothertable 
                WHERE ...

            )
        CONNECT BY PRIOR .. = ....
        )
        ...
```

but in posgres it doesn't work and I see error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "START"
  Position: 282
```

Looks like my postgres doesn't now such syntax.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935842/2674303 I ran:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

But it disn't help.

What could ve wrong ?

postgres version is **11.6**

How to fix it ?

Comment: You can't just take Oracle code and run it in Postgres. You would need to provide sample data, desired results, and you actual query (not just part of it) so one can help rewriting it in Postgres.

Comment: @ GMB  I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/37846191/2674303 - so not -it  doesn't answer

Comment: @GMB I need unified query which works in both

Comment: @GMB In the linked post written that connect by could be enabled by executing CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc what did I wrong?

Comment: Linked post is https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935842/2674303